# Setting field defaults/domains based on subtypes

Tags: arcpy, domains

I have a rather complicated FeatureClass, in which one of the fields has a different default value, and a different domain, depending on the value in the nominated SubType field.

Using the rather useful code in [this example](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/ListSubtypes/018w00000021000000/), I get this output: (trimmed to just the field in question, for length)

```
Code: 1
Default: True
Name: EducationalFacility
SubtypeField: FCSUBTYPE
Fields:
 --Field name: FACILITYTYPE
 --Field default value: 3
 --Domain name: dEducationalFacilityType
Code: 2
Default: False
Name: HospitalFacility
SubtypeField: FCSUBTYPE
Fields:
 --Field name: FACILITYTYPE
 --Field default value: 6
 --Domain name: dHospitalFacilityType
Code: 3
Default: False
Name: CommunityFacility
SubtypeField: FCSUBTYPE
Fields:
 --Field name: FACILITYTYPE
 --Field default value: 3
 --Domain name: dCommunityFacilityType
```

Note the different domains for each subtype value. The `FACILITYTYPE` field itself has *no* domain set.

When I copy this FeatureClass, using `FeatureClassToFeatureClass` with `arcpy.env.transferDomains = True`, I lose all this interesting subtype information. I can recreate the domains for fields that have domains set directly, but I can't work out how to transfer this domain-within-a-subtype stuff with arcpy.